# How can i find anvil GUI nbt?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-data-packs

So i'm trying to to make a datapack, where you can enchant blocks with enchantments on an anvil in survival. I've tried getting player's data, block's data, but i can't find where the anvil GUI nbt is stored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may upset you --- I don't think GUI interactions are open for manipulation by command. [image: /data get entity @s]

See that "isFurnaceGuiOpen" nbt tag? It looks like you can at least detect if a player is interacting with a furnace right? But in fact, it doesn't work.
`execute as @a[nbt={isFurnaceGuiOpen:1b}] run say open_furnace`. The same would apply to something like `isAnvilGuiOpen:1b`.

The truth is, my visual studio datapack add-on doesn't even recognize this nbt tag.

Another thing, you cannot modify the nbt tags of a player.

There might be other approaches to your question. If you want you can explain in detail more about your concept and I will do my best to help.

Comment: Sadly, i guess you can't detect the GUI. I've looked trough all of the player tags, but there was nothing about anvil. I guess i'll use a hopper. Thanks for the help offering, but i already understand datapacks very well. :)